# Dependency walker doesn't see Visual C++ dependency on C# DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dependency-walker

I'm afraid Dependency Walker doesn't support this, but I need to make sure I'm not missing something.

I have a Visual C++ application that depends on a number of DLLs. One of which, is a DLL written as a C# project (CLR support is therefore turned on). In the `.vcxproj` configuration file, I can see additional dependencies like so...

```
<AdditionalDependencies>comprisinterface.lib;wsock32.lib;mpr.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
```

The C# project is called `XLibrary.dll` -- clearly it is not in that list. That's because it has been included in the following tag...

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="System" />
  <Reference Include="System.Messaging" />
  <Reference Include="XLibrary">
    <HintPath>..\..\..\..\XLibrary.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

When I run Dependency Walker, I can see all those DLLs inside the `<AdditionalDependencies>` tag, but I cannot see `XLibrary.dll`

Does Dependency Walker lack CLR support?

Comment: Yes; dependency walker has nothing to do with the CLR.

Comment: If the DLL is loaded at runtime via `LoadLibrary`, then there is no way Dependency Walker will know about it.

Comment: I would think that the Visual C++ DLL binary file has some sort of header or meta data that shows the C# `XLibrary.dll` thought right?

Comment: @KendallWeihe No. Well, there's the CLR metadata, but that's exactly what dependency walker doesn't support.